# Where to find the .py file of a specific tensorflow object in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following preprocessing pipeline in Tensorflow:

```
data_transformation = tf.keras.Sequential([layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomContrast(factor=(0.7,0.9)),layers.GaussianNoise(stddev=tf.random.uniform(shape=(),minval=0, maxval=1)), layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(factor=0.1, fill_mode='reflect', interpolation='bilinear', seed=None, name=None, fill_value=0.0), layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(height_factor=(0.1,0.2), width_factor=(0.1,0.2), fill_mode='reflect', interpolation='bilinear', seed=None, name=None, fill_value=0.0),])
```

I would like to change the layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomContrast.py file to change how it works. However, I don't find such a file in my system. Whenever I found a file, it is an **init**.py file linking to a different directory. I know that, if I declare the following in the python terminal, It returns fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.image.random_contrast
```

But if I look for image in my tensorflow directory, the following returns to me

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/image
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v1/image
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/compat/v2/image
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/kernels/image
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/image
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/api/_v1/keras/preprocessing/image
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/api/keras/preprocessing/image
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/api/_v2/keras/preprocessing/image
```

All of these directories point to **init**.py files again. And it seems in an infinite loop looking for directories that are redirected by **init**.py files. How am I supposed to find the specific .py file of a specific import in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search on the web for :

***tf layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomContrast***

Then follow the first link : [RandomContrast](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RandomContrast) and finally click on ***view source on github*** which will go here: [image_preprocessing.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.8.0/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py#L1123-L1201)